# stop changing display brightness after adaptor removal

Tags: kubuntu

When my AC adaptor unplugs the kubuntu increase the display brightness automatically. How can I stop this so it does not change?

Comment: You must have custom brightness set in Power Management profile. You should be able to change it by opening power setting by clicking on the battery icon in the system tray.

Comment: @AbhishekNair in in power setting -> advance setting -> configure notifications you can select what sound plays or script runs when adapter unplugs but there is no setting for stopping automatic brightness increment.

Comment: I don't have a Kubuntu system handy but this [link](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/powerdevil/index.html) should be helpful. See if there is option of "Energy Saving" in main menu to launch this. There would be individual brightness setting option for AC power and battery.

Answer (score 0):

changing brightness is not an alert. kubuntu has 3 mood in energy saving. on ac, on batter, on low battery. when the you remove the ac and your battery is low it goes on the "on low battery" mood. so if in that mood your brightness is set to be high it will make you think it is an alert.